# pause and resume Windows Media Player in C#

Tags: .net, controls, windows-media-player

I'm making an VoIP application and I just want to be able to pause and resume (and probably check the player state) of Windows Media Player. Solutions I've found on SO refer to WMPLib but this is for embedding WMP in my .NET application. I simply just want to pause and resume the current instance if there is one. Is there documentation for this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with a plugin for WMP that you could then call.  [WMPKeys](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/) does something like this (only it interacts via global keystrokes.)  It's on sourceforge, so its source may be available.

Windows 7 does know how to adjust system volume during times when the microphone is on; rather than pausing, you might want to just adjust volume instead.