# resume a paused mp3 file in c# winforms using WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3, resume

with WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer i am able to play and pause mp3 files but i am not able to resume from the paused point.

Can anybody tell me how to resume the song

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644064/pausing-and-resuming-mp3-with-wmplib-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think that it's quiet easy I use the "Pause" method to pause the song and "Play" method to continue it ::: here is the code that I've used

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wmp.url="the mp3 path that you want to play";
//NOTE::: after the above command the mp3 file or other multimedia file will automatically play.

//And for PAUSING use this code:
wmp.controls.pause();

//AND for continue PLAYING use below code:
wmp.controls.play();
```

this code works for me and I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change media players. Add a reference to this player:`AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer`. I found a reference in  [This project](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/net-framework/simple-media-player/).

I simply changed the player reference. Tweaked the properties: This "`moPlayer.Controls.pause()`" became "`moPlayer.Ctlcontrols.pause()`" and I was in business. I hope this helps. I did this and my player can pause and resume.